# Diet and exercise schema

Tags: schema, database-design

Pardon the brevity but: I am currently working on a project which requires users to create a 12 week diet/exercise regime. I basically need to store 3 meal options for each day which can be made up of multiple different food items. I would appreciate any advice or suggestions - thanks

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're asking. What are your business needs? What do you want to do? What have you already considered? You need to give us more information, or we're going to have to close this as "Not a real question: too vague"

Comment: Not quite a duplicate but elements of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3808/most-effificient-way-to-store-ingredients-in-a-food-database might be useful for you.

Comment: @jcolebrand - thats what 'pardon the brevity' was indicating! I be sure to include more details next time - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I will be brief as well:

You need a table for each of the following:

Users
FoodItems
Meals
12WeekPlan

The 12WeekPlan table would have a record for every meal of every day in the plan.
The Meals table would have a record for every meal.
The FoodItems table would have a record for every individual food item.

You need a table to join Meals to 12WeekPlan, as the 12WeekPlan has many meals in it (and they may repeat).  (many to many relationship)

You also need a table to join Meals to FoodItems, as a meal consists of one or more food items.  FoodItems can exist in more than one meal.  (many to many relationship)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this free data model for a [Dieter Decision Support System](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/diet_decision_support_system/index.htm). I guess you will need to expand it (add also exercise part), to fit your needs.